# What uniquely identifiable attribute should I use for dynamic DataGridViewCheckBoxCell objects so that I can reference them in my test cases?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, appium, mstest

I need to write a test case for a simple grid layout WinForm app in .net4

Following are the screenshot of my app:
[image]

After I hit the "populateBtn" button the rows gets filled with some dummy data:
[image]

Here is the code for the button's click event handler:

```
        private void populateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person[] data = new Person[] {
                new Person { Name = "samman", Age = 32, IsMarried = false, },
                new Person { Name = "tom", Age = 32, IsMarried = false, },
                new Person { Name = "harreld", Age = 32, IsMarried = false, },
            };

            int idx = 0;
            foreach (Person p in data )
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell isMarriedCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();

                isMarriedCell.Value = p.IsMarried;

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.Name, p.Age);
                dataGridView1[2, idx] = isMarriedCell;

                idx++;
            }
        }
```

The most important thing in the above code is the way I am adding the checkbox. I have created `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` object and added it to the third index of each row of the grid.

The app works just fine. But the issue is that I do not understand what attributes should I pass to each of this dynamically created DataGridViewCheckBox so that I can identifies each of them in my test cases.

My requirements are that I need to get the first CheckBox and then click it to see if it works. I am a web developer and in javascript, I would have simply passed a unique "id" attribute to each Checkbox element. I do not know what attribute is similar to "id" for DataGridViewCheckBoxCell or .net WinForm elements in general.

I did try something like `isMarriedCell.AccessibilityObject.Name = $"gridviewcheckbox-{idx}";` , But when I use `inspect` software to inspect the checkboxes, they do not seem to have that Name. Maybe its because `DataGridViewCheckBox` is some sort of wrapper around `Checkbox` and it does not pass its `Name` to the `Checkbox` it creates.

I might also be able to solve this using indexes, but I do not want to do that. In the future I might have to get a checkbox without knowing its exact position in the grid, so I want to use some sort of `id` so that no matter the position, I can still get the checkbox in my test cases.

Please Help. Here is the code for my test case if it helps:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows;
using System;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context) {
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\WinAppDriver.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(400);

            //set the desired capabilities to the PE_ProHat
            DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

            string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"C:\Users\Samman.Adhikari\source\repos\ExperimentingWithDataGridView\ExperimentingWithDataGridView\bin\Debug\ExperimentingWithDataGridView.exe");
            appCapabilities.SetCapability("ms:waitForAppLaunch", "15");
            session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), appCapabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            //set the time out 
            session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

            //change to the window
            session.SwitchTo().Window(session.WindowHandles[0]);

            session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("populateBtn").Click();

            if (session.FindElementByName("Married Row 0").GetAttribute("Toggle.ToggleState") == "0")
            {
                session.FindElementByName("Married Row 0").Click();
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

        }

    }
```

------------ [EDIT] ----------------------------

As matthew suggested in the comment, I also did try using `Tag` but that also didn't work. I got `An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.` error. Here are the changes that I made for this:

In click event handler I added:

```
isMarriedCell.Tag = $"checkbox-{idx}";
```

In test ClassInitialize I added:

```
            if (session.FindElementByTagName("checkbox-0").GetAttribute("Toggle.ToggleState") == "0")
            {
                session.FindElementByTagName("checkbox-0").Click();
            }
```

Comment: What's stopping you from uniquly identify the checkboxes by their cell "coordinates" (row / column) or even just their row number (as there's only one checkbox per row)?

Comment: If you're not using it for anything else, how about using the `.Tag` property?

Comment: @ZoharPeled as I mentioned, in the future the row that I have to target might be dynamic and not the first one. But most importantly, I want to learn. I believed there must be some attribute that I can use in the checkbox itself, rather than using the row or column.

Comment: In that case, go with what @MatthewWatson wrote - the `Tag` property.

Comment: @MatthewWatson . I have updated the original question with your suggestion "Tag". There you will find the changes that I made and what the error I am getting. I think maybe "DataGridViewCheckBoxCell" is a wrapper around actual "CheckBox" and it maybe does not pass the Tag to the checkbox it renders. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ZoharPeled please see the comment above. thanks

Comment: I doubt you can use standard selenium stuff here to find controls. Cells (and i assume columns also) aren't controls. They are just a surfaced class model of the grid but are not controls itself. So find the grid and then use standard grid methods to find the cell you need.

Comment: You can create a custom `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` that set as CellTemplate a custom `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`,which overrides `CreateAccessibilityInstance()` to create its own `DataGridViewCellAccessibleObject` derived object. Here, you can override the `Name` Property and set any value you want. Note that you can assign the `Name` Property of the accessible object only after the Parent DataGridView has been created. So, not in the Constuctor of a Form, but, e.g., in its OnLoad method

Comment: You can also use a hidden Column used to store the indexes (so the order is preserved if the grid is sorted). The Cells provide a ValuePattern, so you can create a filter to single out a Row and access the CheckBox Cell by Type, Column name or Column index